# Bringing Alias properties with Feature Class to Feature Class Tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, feature-class, alias

I am using arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, outWorkspace, fc) to move many FC's to a new location.  I have found that it is only bringing the FC Name property and imposing that on the Alias property(see below). 
[image: original FC properties]

[image: after I run the FCtoFC tool]

Comment: Try Copy_management(From,To) to copy the data http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000051000000 - don't worry about the {Data Type} it really has no impact on what you're trying to do; I've never encountered a situation where I would need to fill it out but theoretically if you had a shapefile and raster with the same 'name' in the same folder you would need to specify which one you wanted.